# Maximum latitude of a great circle

Tags: circles, geodesy

1 - I am trying to figure out the longitude at which a geodetic great circle reaches its apex. (I have a point and the azimuth at that point identifying the circle)
[I have found a good resource that shows how to find the maximum latitude itself (and the azimuth at that latitude)](http://what-when-how.com/the-3-d-global-spatial-data-model/the-geodetic-line-geometrical-geodesy-the-3-d-global-spatial-data-model/) but I cannot figure out how to find the longitude at that point.

2 - Also related how can we find the longitudes at which a geodetic great circle intersects a given parallel?

EDIT:
The provided link shows sections from the book [The 3-D Global Spatial Data Model
Foundation of the Spatial Data Infrastructure
Earl F . Burkholder](http://www.crcnetbase.com/doi/abs/10.1201/9781420063035.ch6)

EDIT2: If it is of any help i have access to forward/inverse geodesy functions. 
I can find a point and the azimuth at that point given a point-bearing-distance.
I can find the distance-bearing between any given 2 points.

Comment: Why should there be a (unique) longitude?  Even modelling the earth as a prolate spheroid, the longest "great circle" would be invariant under rotation around the earth's axis of rotation.

Comment: edited for clarity. I already have a point and azimuth so it is a unique great circle hence i can use the Clairaut’s Constant mentioned in the link

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by the azimuth of a great circle at a point? I am unfamiliar with geodesy terminology.

Comment: [link](http://what-when-how.com/the-3-d-global-spatial-data-model/the-geodetic-line-geometrical-geodesy-the-3-d-global-spatial-data-model/)  Azimuth is the angle from true north measured clockwise. See figure 6.10 in the link

Comment: The article that you linked to is a confused mish-mash of half-truths and misremembered facts, if you ask me. Does your given point lie on the equator? If so, it's easy. If not, we need more data from you.

Comment: The point does not necessarily lie on the equator. One point (lat/lon) and the azimuth at that point identifies a unique great circle. Just like a point and a slope would uniquely identify a line on the Cartesian coordinate system. If you think more data is necessary to solve this please let me know what is missing

Comment: I don't understand the other comments. There is one degree of freedom among the great circles passing through a point, which is determined by the azimuth angle. The problem seems perfectly well-defined to me.

Comment: Sorry, you are both right. There is enough data.

Comment: On the other hand, while [Clairaut's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation) applies to arbitrary surfaces of revolution, including ellipsoids, I don't think you can get the longitude of the maximum point in closed form unless you have a sphere. Is a spherical earth a valid assumption for geodesy?

Comment: I cannot assume the earth to be spheric. If specific model is needed you can assume WGS84 datum. On the other hand using the equation at 6.68 i can find the latitude itself and the azimuth at that point using Caliraut, for someone math sawy i assume the longitude is also deducable.